# price_level is been returned in google place details API results

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-places-api

l am currently building a simple app that needs to display the price_level and using google places API for this. The google API docs happen to say the price_level will be returned by default. l currently have this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJpQ_l7xpceUgR0O6qrFfwdY8&key={API_KEY_HERE} in place, but can't seem to see the price_level in the results returned. Is there something that l am going wrong or do l need to pass the price_level as a parameter?

[Results returned from the JSON API image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRNZ7.png)

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a `price_level` if there's no price information on Google Maps.  Similarly, there will only be `opening_hours` if Google Maps knows the hours, etc.